# spring batch read different files at runtime

Tags: spring-batch, reader

I have a spring batch job which need to be configurable. In the sense,it should be able to read different files depending on what is passed and build the reader and possibly each different reader will have its own writer. Below example reads one file and I call its writer. How can I make load_area.txt to be dynamic.

```
   @Bean
  public Step orderStep() {
      return stepBuilderFactory.get("loadAStep")
              .<FieldSetter, FieldSetter> chunk(3)
              .reader(reader())
              .processor(processor())
              .writer(writer())
              .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public FlatFileItemReader<FieldSetter> reader() {
      FlatFileItemReader<FieldSetter> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<FieldSetter>();
      reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("load_a.txt"));
      reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<GenericFieldSetter>() {{
          setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|") {{
              setNames(new String[] { "sCode","cName"});
          }});
          setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<FieldSetter>() {{
              setTargetType(FieldSetter.class);
          }});
      }});
      return reader;
  }

   @Bean
  public ItemWriter<GenericFieldSetter> writer() {
    return new LoadAreaItemWriter();
  }
```

load_a.txt
  22|RRR

load_b.txt
  aa|ABCDED|123|0000

I want to read load_a.txt or load_b.txt at runtime depending on what is passed and write its own writer. there is a chance it can be .txt or any type.

FieldSetter.java has setters and getters

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jobExecutionContext`/ `stepExecutionContext`  to pass the file name dynamically. Your bean should have  `@StepScope`.

this is how you can access  `jobExecutionContext`/ `stepExecutionContext`

```
@Bean
 @StepScope
  public FlatFileItemReader<FieldSetter> reader("#{jobExecutionContext['fileName']}") final String fileName ,@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filename1) {
      FlatFileItemReader<FieldSetter> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<FieldSetter>();
      reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(fileName));
      reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<GenericFieldSetter>() {{
          setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|") {{
              setNames(new String[] { "sCode","cName"});
          }});
          setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<FieldSetter>() {{
              setTargetType(FieldSetter.class);
          }});
      }});
      return reader;
  }
```